# A method that uses machine operation data to predict how many days until this machine will fail

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, predictive-models, survival, anomaly-detection

Suppose there is a machine that operates every day, and time series data of its operating conditions can be obtained for each day.
In this case, I want to use machine learning or etc. to detect when the machine is showing signs of failure and how many days later it will fail.

- What is the most common way to do this?
- Is it common to use supervised learning to perform a regression that outputs the number of days after a certain data using the data where a failure occurred?

I think there is a problem with handling the case where no failure occurs.

- Also, if it is difficult to accurately predict how many days later a machine will fail because the variance is relatively large from machine to machine, what is the general approach?
- Is it reasonable to train the model as a classification problem with a certain range of time, such as one week, two weeks, etc.?

Comment: Sounds like [tag:survival-analysis]

Comment: if you have only one machine that failed only once or twice in your dataset, ML won't help you